# Docker build failed for npm package in codebuild

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I have the following script to build my docker image through AWS codebuild

```
FROM node:alpine3.13 as builder
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/client
WORKDIR /usr/src/client
ENV PATH /usr/src/client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/client/package.json
RUN rm package.json && npm i
RUN npm install -g npm@7.6.3
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
RUN mv node_modules/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
COPY . /usr/src/client
RUN npm run build
```

The error log is here

```
Removing intermediate container 97a9752b883e
 ---> 2fc4801c740c
Step 8/17 : RUN rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 ---> Running in 93d506baa75a
Removing intermediate container 93d506baa75a
 ---> 20a8e4cec3ab
Step 9/17 : RUN mv node_modules/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 ---> Running in 5aec0359d42c
mv: can't rename 'node_modules/npm': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c mv node_modules/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' returned a non-zero code: 1

[Container] 2021/03/18 08:56:34 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest . exit status 1
[Container] 2021/03/18 08:56:34 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/03/18 08:56:34 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .. Reason: exit status 1
```

I tried many solutions from here but the build is still failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Go read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Your question is unreadable.

Comment: @JimStewart I updated it. Looking for your help